# What is the correct way to receive a boolean from the StandardMessageCodec?

Tags: flutter, flutter-platform-channel

In the standard codec, [it states](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/StandardMessageCodec-class.html#:%7E:text=bool%3A%20NSNumber%20numberWithBool%3A) that `bool` values are represented as NSNumbers and that when you receive them in iOS, you do so [using NSNumber numberWithBool](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-obj-c-tab#codec). In my iOS platform specific call `(void)handleMethodCall:(FlutterMethodCall *)call` I was doing something like this to extract the bool value and use it:

```objectivec
NSNumber *myvalue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:(NSNumber *)call.arguments[@"myvalue"]];
local.object = [myvalue boolValue];
```

However, I found that no matter the boolean value supplied in my method argument of `myvalue` that it would always resolve to `true`. After changing some things, I decided to try to see if I could extract the bool value directly using the code below:

```objectivec
BOOL myvalue = [[call.arguments objectForKey:@"myvalue"] boolValue];
local.object = myvalue;
```

I was successful, but I wanted to validate that I am doing the correct idiomatic thing. The code that was successful feels like it is running counter to what the flutter documentation states and I just want to validate that I am doing things correctly. Is this okay to do? Should I be doing something else instead?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to serialize your messages using **protobuf** and forget about all these type conversions.

https://pub.dev/packages/protoc_plugin is the *dart* plugin for [protoc](https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/) command. There is similar plugin for *swift/objC*. It can generate *java/kotlin* by default.

In this approach, your data classes for dart and native sides will be generated by *protoc*. These classes provide an encoder to/decoder from a binary format (i.e. not json or xml or such). You can use these facilities to transmit encoded messages to other side and decode it there into a platform-specific data class.

You can find some tutorial resources, for example take a look at this article:
https://medium.com/@er.mayursharma14/setup-protobuf-for-flutter-plugin-method-channel-cdca4018ae09

Comment: I like this, but I'm patching a library and they don't use protobufs yet. I will save this for a later thought and bring it up to them to see if the change is worth it.